# export csv file for selected rows from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have created a datatable using the following examples:

1.[Individual column searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

2.[File export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

And my code is as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({'scrollX':true, 'dom': 'lBfrtip','buttons': ['csv']});

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

This code is working perfectly. Now I want to export only selected rows without changing the datatable structure in example 1. I am not an expert in Jquery. So can anyone can help me please? Also is it possible add checkboxes for selecting rows?

Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific? please elaborate on "selected rows"

Comment: I have N number of rows in my table. User can select rows based on available information in tables (different column will provide different information) and then they can download those selected rows as csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do that by using following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({'scrollX':true, 'dom': 'lBfrtip',buttons: [{ extend: 'csv',text: 'CSV all'},{extend: 'csv',text: 'CSV selected',exportOptions: {modifier: {selected: true}}}],select: true});

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

So I have added new code in my existing script.

```
buttons: [{ extend: 'csv',text: 'CSV all'},{extend: 'csv',text: 'CSV selected',exportOptions: {modifier: {selected: true}}}],select: true
```